# Cloud Function scheduled for deletion for more than 20 minutes

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-run

I try to delete a Cloud Function. No matter if I try to do it from the gCloud CLI, firebase CLI or from the web console, the result is the same. From the CLI, I get a timeout. From the console, it puts the function in the queue, but it never gone.

If I try to remove it from the Google Cloud Run console, I can not because the `delete` button is disabled with a message that says `Service selected is already scheduled for deletion`.

At the moment of writing this post, the function was in this state of scheduled for deletion for more than 20 minutes, so I suppose that something is wrong there.

In the logs, no message since I tried for the fist time.

What can I do?

NOTE: Checking the logs, looks like is in a loop, trying to deploy the function again and again, and the deployment is failing. Even if I try to remove it, it never stop.

NOTE: If I try to redeploy the function, I get next error: `ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) ResponseError: status=[409], code=[Ok], message=[Could not update Cloud Run service projects/***/locations/us-central1/services/***. Resource 'beforecreateuser' cannot be created or modified because it is currently being deleted.]`

BTW: It's so bad that GCP does not give free support for this cases. I hope they are not charging for this function.